# How to resolve errors due to duplicate java files in Eclipse project ? The type 'xxx.java' already defined error

Tags: eclipse, maven

I was having a perfectly working project in Eclipse IDE
for Enterprise Java and Web Developers
Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043

Suddenly, when I login to the Remote Desktop where my Eclipse was installed, in the `package explorer as well as in project explorer`, I started seeing an error reported that  certain java file is  'present already'. I see the below **project structure** as shown.

I tried project-->refresh/clean, maven clean etc. for no help

**BTW, when I run the 'maven test' it runs despite the display of the error. It is also building fine also.**

I saw similar issues reported in SO already, but could not resolve.
[image]
**ANSWER:(Found via @nitind comment)**
The folder structure under src/main/java is shown. Based on @nitind comments, I discovered this. It appears I am blind and as well as dumb. Lol ! Thanks to the extra pair of intelligent eyes.

[image]

Comment: Those are actually two parts of the tree showing the **same** file, not two different files for the same type. You can see this as the part of the tree showing Java types is showing the test source folder path before it starts showing the package and type structure. This is not a good time to mangle the error message about which type is duplicated and make it more generic. Which one is it actually complaining about? Do you already have some version of the duplicated class somewhere else on the Build Path, like in a jar?

Comment: @nitind
Thanks for the quick response. 
From with in the 'Problems' view, show the resource option of the error takes me to the AndroidTestBSVenkata.java present under src/test/java folder with the package name 'com.zq.mobile.browser.test;  As it is also present in the src folder down below in the PackageExplorer. BTW, when I run the 'maven test' it runs despite the display of the error. It is building fine also.

Comment: What's the structure under `src/main/java`?

Comment: @nitind 
Bro ! It appears I am blind and as well as dumb.
I am migrating test classes that were kept under src/main/java on to src/test/java. I observed that I have left the AndroidTestBSVenkata.java still under src/main/java which might be the reason. Probably I should be removing it. 
I updated the main question with the new pic snippet.

Comment: @nitind comment provided me the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nitind Bro ! It appears I am blind and as well as dumb. I am migrating test classes that were kept under src/main/java on to src/test/java. I observed that I have left the AndroidTestBSVenkata.java still under src/main/java which might be the reason. Probably I should be removing it. I updated the main question with the new pic snippet.

Yes, I confirm that once I renamed the file under src/main/java from AndroidTestBSVenkata.java to AndroidTestBSVenkataTBD.java, the error went away. Obviously.

Your comment prompted me to the right answer.